# Wrong number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, long-integer

I got a question, because long should store 32 bits, `eax` should store 32 bits as well. But why it doesn't store up to 4mln? Instead of 4,000,000,000 it prints me -294967296 all the time.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: you may want to try an `unsigned long`.

Comment: Is there a way to use unsigned in assembly?

Comment: Not really. It is up to whoever prints the number to interpret it as signed or unsigned. E.g. in C you could use format "%lu" instead of "%ld" or use strtoul(3) instead of strtol(3).

Comment: How are you printing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using it as a *signed* 32-bit integer type, so the values are in the range [-2147483648, 2147483647].

I haven't done any assembly for a *very* long time, but if you use it as an unsigned type instead, you'll get a range of [0, 4294967295].

Comment: Is there a way to use unsigned type in assembly?

Comment: @sadasfsdafasfgasgasd Assembly data types don't distinguish between signed or unsigned types. It's the instructions that do, and only a subset of them. What you're seeing is the effect of *printing out* a 32-bit integer as if it were signed.